# css issue while using with GridView control

Tags: css, gridview, cross-browser

I have a gridview control in which one css class is applied. Following is css content of my code:

```
/* Team */
.TeamBox{display:block;margin-bottom:10px;}
.TeamBox table{border:0 none transparent;border-collapse:collapse; width:100%;}
.TeamBox table th, .TeamBox table td{border:0 none transparent;text-align:left;}
.TeamBox table th{font-weight:600!important;font-style:italic;border-bottom:1px solid #f7f7f7;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;}
.TeamBox table td {padding-left:15px; float:left;}
```

And the declaration part is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMaster" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h2 class="ms-webpart-titleText" style="text-align: justify;">
            <nobr><asp:Label ID="lblWebTitle" runat="server" ></asp:Label> <span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ6"></span></nobr>
        </h2>
        <div class="TeamBox">
            <asp:GridView ID="MangersGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="MangersGrid_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Team Managers" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div class="TeamBox">

            <asp:GridView ID="MembersGrid" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="MembersGrid_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Team Member" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am getting different output in different browser.

Below is the image which shows the grid in FireFox.

[image]

Below is the image which shows the grid in IE.

[image]

I want to remove the lines which comes in every item of the grid.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just I needed to set the property of the GridView control. i.e., GridLines="None" and got the perfect output.

Hope this helps others too.